# How I can use classes with same name EF 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have multiple EDMX files in same project. All files targeting same database.

Table 'Customers' occurred two times but in different EDMX files.

Is there way to use classes with same names in different EDMX files?

My code:

```
using (var con = new TestEntities())
        {
            var q1 = con.ADDRESS.ToList();
            foreach (var item in q1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.CITY);
            }
        }

        using (var con2 = new TestEntities1())
        {
            var q2 = con2.ADDRESS.ToList();
            foreach (var item in q2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.CITY);
            }
        }
```

On second query "q2" I get error: The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type.

First works normally.

Thanks

Comment: Can you set a namespace on the .edmx properties, so code for that .edmx file is all within that namespace?  Haven't used EF but you can in LINQ .dbml so I'd assume it's possible in EF.

Comment: Namespace for first model is: HAS_Communicator_TESTModel, and for Second model is: HAS_Communicator_TESTModel1. I used different namespaces.

Comment: Ok, then perhaps you have a problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927391/the-mapping-of-clr-type-to-edm-type-is-ambiguous-with-ef-6-5, suggests you need to use distinct class names as the EF machinery uses just the class name not the FQN internally somewhere. No idea if this is still accurate however. Sorry!

Comment: Yes I have that problem. I review this post but trying to found solution. For now I will forgot option with classes with same names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the namespace for each of your models. Select the model in the solution explorer, right click and select properties. In the properties window change the `Custom Tool Namespace` for each model. For example if you have `TestEntities.edmx` and give it a `Custom Tool Namespace` of `TestEntities`, then your entities will be accessible under `TestEntities.ADDRESS`.

Repeat this for all models in your project so your `TestEntities1.edmx` file gets assigned to `TestEntities1` and the `ADDRESS` objects will be accessible using `TestEntities1.ADDRESS`.

Comment: I have models with different namespaces already, but it doesn't work.