# "the entity type is not part of the model for the current context" error is thrown when project contains more than one EDMX file

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-database-first

I'm using database first and I have a `switch` statement that looks something like this:

```
switch (site)
{
    case Site.One:
        using (OneContext one = new OneContext())
            return one.OrganizationObjects.SingleOrDefault(x => x.u_Name == orgName)?.g_org_id;
    case Site.Two:
        using (TwoContext two = new TwoContext())
            return two.OrganizationObjects.SingleOrDefault(x => x.u_Name == orgName)?.g_org_id;
    default:
        throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Both databases are pretty similar and have almost the all of the same models.

If I delete the "Two" EDMX file and comment out the condition, then OneContext works perfectly. 
 If I add the TwoContext EDMX file to the project and run the code again, the "OneContext" code fails when it tries to query `OrganizationObjects.`

I made sure each context was using the correct connection string, but this error still occurs:

[image]

Comment: Both edmx is in same folder ?

Comment: @Eldho Yeah. It's multiple EDMXs in the same folder. Should they be in different folders if the models are similar?

Comment: Could you try separating these multiple folders. I had a problem like if second edmx is added i got missing the first edmx tt classes. it worked when seperated.

Comment: @Eldho Thanks for the advice. Testing now.

Comment: @Eldho Moving the EDMX files to their own folders didn't fix the problem. But it gave me a new error that is a little less cryptic. It boils down to the issue of having the same entity name in multiple contexts: `The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type`

Comment: @Eldho I was finally able to resolve the issue. This was the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33175287/1339826. I was able to add a field to the tables to make the objects unique.

Comment: if you have resolved it post here too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Workaround: Change a property on one of the two identical classes.**
>
> EF matches on class name AND class properties.  So I just changed a
>   property name on one of the EF objects, and the error is gone.
>
> As @Entrodus commented on one of the other answers:
>
> > EF collision happens only when two classes have the same name AND the
> >     same set of parameters.

[The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous with EF 6 & 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927391/the-mapping-of-clr-type-to-edm-type-is-ambiguous-with-ef-6-5/33175287#33175287)

Answer (score -1):

Entity Framework matches on class name and class properties. Two classes with the same class name and same properties results in conflict.

Change a property on one of the two identical classes will solve the issue.