# The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I have two Databases but both databases have same schema.I have added their edmx  files in different folders to separate namespaces but still I am getting this exception:

```
The mapping of CLR type to EDM type is ambiguous because multiple CLR types match the EDM type 'bettingoffer'. Previously found CLR type 'SpocosyPanel.Data.Tennis.bettingoffer', newly found CLR type 'SpocosyPanel.Data.Soccer.bettingoffer'.
```

My question is how can I use two edmx files which are apparently same but from different data sources

Comment: This is possible duplicate but it is same error but other question does not have answer yet. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14927391/the-mapping-of-clr-type-to-edm-type-is-ambiguous-with-ef-6-5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a known bug in Entity Framework 6 and below. 
You could not use the same databases even though they are on different namespaces. This is happening in code first design as well and a post was opened on [GitHub](http://This%20is%20already%20supported%20in%20the%20EF7%20code%20base.%20We%20didn't%20really%20do%20anything%20to%20explicitly%20support%20it,%20it%20was%20just%20a%20side%20effect%20of%20the%20lighterweight%20purpose%20built%20metadata%20system%20in%20EF7%20smile.) regarding the issue as well.

One of the developers even answered it stating:

> This is already supported in the EF7 code base. We didn't really do
>   anything to explicitly support it, it was just a side effect of the
>   lighterweight purpose built metadata system in EF7 smile.

Meaning, that if you use Entity Framework 6 or below there is not much for you to do except not using the same Database twice in your code.

Comment: So whats the solution?

Comment: There is non for Entity Framework 6 and below, this bug will forever stand as the fix only applied for Entity Framework 7. You will have to use different databases.

Comment: The most effective workaround is to rename either the entity (EDM) class or the CLR class, if you can. Sometimes having a different public property between the classes will also work; even changing the name sometimes works.